# XeLaTeX and EPS figure with consistent fonts

Tags: xetex, labels, pstricks, psfrag

I'm using Miktex 2.9 and XeLaTeX plus some EPS figures. For consistent fonts throughout the document, I used to play with [psfrag](http://ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) or directly use [pstricks](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks). I'm facing the situation where none of the above works. Instead, I'm now using the `\put` command to place labels on EPS figures. I'd like to know others possibles approaches : Inkscape? [tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)?

Comment: Hmmm, what have you tried with psfrag? The standard approaches of pst-pdf or pstool shouldn't be too hard to get working, if they don't work out of the box.

Comment: I have to investigate. I know that pstricks and xelatex should be working together. For psfrag, I just used a former piece of code and it was not compiling. It looks like xelatex does not accept postscript specials, that may be the problem.

Comment: I'm having a look at your pstool package. Thanks

Comment: Will, pstool and psfrag work very well together with pdflatex but not with xelatex. If you have a work around, I'm highly interested. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the `overpic` package which provides an environment of included graphics `picture` overlay.  You can definitely use pgf/tikz, but if you're not already it might be overkill.

Comment: thanks. It looks very similar to what I am doing by hand now

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this [document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) describing a solution for SVGs coming from Inkscape. Haven’t tried it myself yet.