# problem with psfrag, eps file and texworks

Tags: eps

I need to compile file using psfrag ans eps figure. I use texworks on windows and I have read that there are problems with pdflatex and I should go the latex->dvi->ps way but all I have found so far is not at all understandable for me... could you help me please? Thanks by advance :)

Comment: It seems that TexWorks doesn't want to hear anything about latex… The only thing I see is to use another editor, like TexMaker, TexStudio or TexnicCenter, which take latex into consideration. Or maybe try xelatex with TexWorks, as xelatex first produces a dvi file before converting to pdf.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately Xelatex reply is : ! Undefined control sequence.
\pfg@hidestart ...unt@ by\@ne \repeat \Gin@PS@raw 
                                                  {/PSfrag where{pop\pfg@ \t...

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work with psfragx either, as results from this discussion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63258/psfrag-or-comparable-tagging-method-with-xetex So there remains the possibilty of installing another editor…

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85417/configuring-texworks-processing-tools help? TeXworks is focussed on a PDF-based route but will work with a toolchain for DVI-based compilation: you just have to do a little set up.

Comment: OK, I'll dupe to that then