# PSfrag does not replace tags but inserts the replacement text

Tags: xetex, includegraphics, psfrag

I want to replace a tag in a eps figure using the \psfrag command. Here is the code of the figure:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \psfrag{r}[cB][cB]{Radius}
    \includegraphics{02_Grundlagen/eps/Coordinate_System.eps}
    \caption{Coordinate System}
\end{figure}
```

In the attached screenshot you can see, the psfrag does not replace the "r" but instead lists the PSfrag replacement "Radius" on the left side of the image.
[image: Screenshot of the wrong psfrag replacement]

I am using Visual Studio Code with the following recipe: xelatex➞makeindex➞xelatex➞bibtex➞xelatex.2x

I am looking forward to your help!
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. What is your minimal working example in tex code? We not have 02_Grundlagen/eps/Coordinate_System.eps file.

Comment: Can we see the eps file somewhere?

Comment: you can't use psfrag with xelatex. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63258/2388